# How to replace MySQL functions with PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

When reading on [php.net](http://php.net) about *MySQL functions*. I encountered this message

> Warning 
>   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)
> - [PDO::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

I've read about PDO. How can I update my code to PDO using either MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: Great stuff. I thought this was going to be a lazy question, and it turns out to be an excellent self-answer!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I see a lot of code posted on SO implementing *my_sql functions*. And comments from others (including myself) pressing the questioners to abandon *MySQL functions* and start using PDO or MySQLI. This post is here to help. You can refer to it as it provides explanation to why they are deprecated and what *PDO* is, plus a minimal code example to implement PDO.

*First of all:*

Conversion from *mysql functions* to *PDO* is not a simple case of search and replace. PDO is an Object Oriented Programming add on for the PHP language.
That means an other approach in writing the code as with the *mysql functions*. First why convert?

### Why are *mysql functions* deprecated?

> The mysql extension is ancient and has been around since PHP 2.0, released 15 years ago (!!); which is a decidedly different beast than the modern PHP which tries to shed the bad practices of its past. The mysql extension is a very raw, low-level connector to MySQL which lacks many convenience features and is thereby hard to apply correctly in a secure fashion; it's therefore bad for noobs. Many developers do not understand SQL injection and the mysql API is fragile enough to make it hard to prevent it, even if you're aware of it. It is full of global state (implicit connection passing for instance), which makes it easy to write code that is hard to maintain. Since it's old, it may be unreasonably hard to maintain at the PHP core level.

> The mysqli extension is a lot newer and fixes all the above problems. PDO is also rather new and fixes all those problems too, plus more.

> Due to these reasons* the mysql extension will be removed sometime in the future.

*source [Deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859477/why-are-phps-mysql-functions-deprecated)*

### How to implement PDO

PDO offers one solution for connecting to multiple databases. This answer covers only *MySQL* and *MSSQL* servers.

**Connecting to a *MySQL* database, prerequisites**

This is fairly simple and doesn't require any pre set-up of PHP. Modern PHP installations are standard shipped with a module that allows PDO connections to MySQL servers.

> The module is `php_pdo_mysql.dll`

**Connecting to a *MSSQL* database, prerequisites**

This is a more advanced set-up. You need `php_pdo_sqlsrv_##_ts.dll` or `php_pdo_sqlsrv_##_nts.dll drivers`. They are version specific hence the `##`. At the moment of writing, Microsoft has released
official drivers for PHP 5.5.x. The 5.6 drivers aren't yet officially released by Microsoft, but are available as non-official builds by [others](http://robsphp.blogspot.nl/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html).

> The module is `php_pdo_sqlsrv_##_ts.dll` for the thread safe variant
> The module is `php_pdo_sqlsrv_##_nts.dll` for the non-thread safe variant

**Connecting to a database using PDO**
To connect to a database you need to create a *new PDO instance* from the *PDO construct*.

```
$connection = new PDO(arguments);
```

The PDO constructor takes 1 required arguments and 3 optional.

1. DSN or *Data Source Name*, mostly this is a string containing information about the driver, host and database name. Since PHP 7.4 it can also include username and password.
2. Username
3. Password
4. Options

**Connecting to *MySQL***

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=databasename;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

Let's take a look at `$dsn`: First it defines the driver (`mysql`). Then the database name and finally the host.

**Connecting to *MSSQL***

```
$dsn = 'sqlsrv:Server=127.0.0.1;Database=databasename';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

Let's take a look at `$dsn`: First it defines the driver (`sqlsrv`). Then the host and finally the database name.

When you create the instance a connection is made to the database. You only have to do this once during the execution of a PHP script.

> To throw errors returned by your SQL server add this options to your PDO instance using `setAttribute`:   `$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`

### Performing queries

PDO uses *prepared statements*. This is a real difference between *PDO's* approach and *mysql functions*. The latter was very susceptible to *SQL-INJECTION*. One would build a query like this:

```
$SQL = 'SELECT ID FROM users WHERE user = '.$username ;
```

When a malicious website or person posts the username `injector; DROP TABLE users`. The results will be devastating. You needed to proof your code by escaping and encapsulating strings and variables with quotes. This had to be done
for every query. On larger websites or poorly maintained code the risk of having a form that allowed SQL injection could become very high. Prepared statements eliminates the chance of first tier SQL injection like the example above.

The PDO drivers act as a man-in-the-middle between your PHP-server and database server, called a *data-access abstraction* layer. It doesn't rewrite your SQL queries, but do offer a generic way to connect to multiple database types
and handles the insertion of variables into the query for you. *Mysql functions* constructed the query on execution of the PHP code. With PDO the query actually gets build on the database server.

A prepared SQL example:

```
$SQL = 'SELECT ID, EMAIL FROM users WHERE user = :username';
```

Note the difference; Instead of a PHP variable using `$` outside the string, we introduce a variable using `:` within the string. Another way is:

```
$SQL = 'SELECT ID, EMAIL FROM users WHERE user = ?';
```

**How to perform the actual query**

Your PDO instance provides two methods of executing a query. When you have no variables you can use `query()`, with variables use `prepare()`. `query()` is immediately executed upon calling. Please note the object oriented way of the call (`->`).

```
$result = $connection->query($SQL);
```

**The prepare method**

The *prepare method* takes two arguments. The first is the SQL string and the second are options in the form of an Array. A basic example

```
$connection->prepare($SQL, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
```

In our SQL string example we've used a named variable called `:username`. We still need to bind a PHP variable, integer or string to it. We can do this in two ways. Either build an array containing the named variables as `key` or use the method `bindParam` or `bindValue`.
I will explain the array variant and the method `bindValue` for the sake of simplicity.

*`Array`*
You can do something like this for named variables, where you provide the *variable* as *array key*:

```
$queryArguments = array(':username' => $username);
```

And this for indexed variables (`?`):

```
$queryArguments = array($username);
```

When you have added all the variables you need you can call upon the method `execute()` to perform the query. Thereby passing the array as argument to the function `execute`.

```
$result = $connection->execute($queryArguments);
```

*`bindValue`*
The *bindValue* method allows you to bind values to the *PDO instance*. The method takes two required arguments and one optional. The optional arguments set the data-type of the value.

For named variables:

```
$connection->bindValue(':username', $username);
```

For indexed variables:

```
$connection->bindValue(1, $username);
```

After binding the values to the instance, you can call upon `execute` without passing any arguments.

```
$result = $connection->execute();
```

> NOTE: You can only use a named variable once! Using them twice will result in a failure to execute the query. Depending on your settings this will or will not throw an error.

### Fetching the results

Again I will only cover the basics for fetching results from the returned set. PDO is a fairly advanced add-on.

**Using `fetch` and `fetchAll`**

If you did a *select query* or executed a *stored procedure* that returned a result set:

*`fetch`*
`fetch` is a method that could take up to three optional arguments. It fetches a single row from the result set. By default it returns an *array* containing the column names as keys and indexed results.
Our example query could return something like

```
ID      EMAIL
1       someone@example.com
```

`fetch` will return this as:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [EMAIL] => someone@example.com
    [1] => someone@example.com
)
```

To echo all output of a result set:

```
while($row = $result->fetch())
{
    echo $row['ID'];
    echo $row['EMAIL'];
}
```

There are other options you can find here: [fetch_style](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php);

*`fetchAll`*
Fetches all rows in a single array. Using the same default option as `fetch`.

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
```

If you used a query that didn't return results like a insert or update query you can use the method `rowCount` to retrieve the amount of rows affected.

---

### A simple class:

```
class pdoConnection {
    public $isConnected;

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct($dsn, $username, $password, $options = array()) {
        $this->isConnected = true;
        $this->connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //sets the default to return 'named' properties in array.
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        $this->connection = null;
        $this->isConnected = false;
    }

    public function query($SQL) {
        return $this->connection->query($SQL);
    }

    public function prepare($SQL, $params = array()) {
        $result = $this->connection->prepare($SQL);
        $result->execute($params);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=databasename;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$db = new pdoConnection($dsn, $user, $password);

$SQL = 'SELECT ID, EMAIL FROM users WHERE user = :username';
$result = $db->prepare($SQL, array(":username" => 'someone'));

while($row = $result->fetch())
{
    echo $row['ID'];
    echo $row['EMAIL'];
}
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile to post this in one of the more canonical questions (easier to find, more exposure). Explaining the exception usage is nice, but maybe less suitable and a distraction when transitioning off from mysql functions. Downconverting PDOExceptions into plain Exceptions seems inadvisable even. The pdoConnection wrapper is also complicating your PDO introduction, and a bit redundant apart from the combined prepare+execute convenience method.

Comment: Note that by default, PDO's "prepared statements" aren't really prepared statements but are only emulated (by escaping values internally) for performance reasons. You need to explicitly set some options on the PDO connection object to enable real prepared statements.

Comment: @AndréDaniel, to my knowledge that depends on the driver and version of the SQL server. MSSQL by default isn't emulated. Above MySQL 4.1 it also natively prepares and not emulates.

Comment: @Mario. Thanks for your thoughts. Could you elaborate more about this part of your comment: "*Downconverting PDOExceptions into plain Exceptions seems inadvisable even*"?

Comment: "it also natively prepares" [or not](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#596).

Comment: How do you get an insert id with your PDO pdoConnection class?

Comment: `$db->connection->lastInsertId();` should do it! But take a look at the [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)-page. There are better and more secure ways.

Comment: `$db->connection->lastInsertId();`  - did you try it yourself? It doesn't work for me. Also, I am genuinely interested, "what are such better and more secure ways"? The page you linked to doesn't explain any

Comment: In the examples on the page there are examples of insert queries returning the value wanted.

Comment: But examples are using the same PDO::lastInsertId(), not some " better and more secure ways" you mentioned. It works with vanilla PDO but it doesn't with your custom class.

Comment: Since `$connection` is protected you need to add a function for it or set it to public to access it's properties and methods.