# PHP get variable from on table and then use that variable to select from a second table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm building a followers list for a user. I have two tables the first shows the relationships between users and the second table holds every users profile info. In the following code, I first select from the user relationships table to get a **variable {$userid1}** which is the value of all the user ids that follow the current user. When I echo out {$userid1} I get all the ids of the users who follow the current user but it is one giant connected string. I want to take the variable {$userid1} and use it to pull every one of those follower's user data from the profile table. **I want every user's data to show up from the profile table that follows the current user.** The code works however only the newest follower's profile data is pulled from the profile table. I was thinking putting the variable {$userid1} into an array and using foreach, but I'm not sure how the syntax would be. Anybody know how it could work? The problem is a variable can only hold one value at a time.

Output of the first query are the iduser numbers from the users following the current user.

e.g. when echoed `echo $userid1 . " ";` the results are the ids look like this: **45 56 67** 
I added a space between numbers in the echo statement.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM followrelations Where iduser2='$uid' "); //followers from relations table
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$userid1 = $row['iduser1']; 
echo $userid1 . " ";


}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile where iduser=$userid1 ORDER BY username ");//get followers infor from profile using variable
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
    $iduserf = $row['iduser'];  //userid2 requires different var name so program does not get mixed up                      
    $username = $row['username'];
    $bio = $row['bio'];
    $avatar = $row['avatar'];

echo "
<div style='width:500px;height:100px;padding:20px 20px;float:left;border: solid black 1px;'>
<a href='profile.php?uid=$iduserf'><img src=$avatar height=50px width=50px /></a></br>
<a href='profile.php?uid=$iduserf'>$username </a></br>
</div>" ;

}
```

Comment: Please add the output of the first query to your question.

Comment: e.g. when echoed: echo $userid1 . " "; the results are the ids look like this: 45 56 67 I added a space between numbers in the echo statement.
@JeremiahWinsley

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for subqueries:

```
SELECT username 
FROM user_table 
WHERE id IN( SELECT user_id WHERE linked_user_id = 123 )
```

This is simplefied to be a better example. This will select the username of all users from the `user_table`, where the ID exist in the subquery.
In turn, the subquery selects all `user_id` where the linked user has `id=123`.
The subquery is quite similar to making an array in PHP and use that info for the next query.

*Small note: Be carefull with subqueries. They're perfect in my example above, but eg not all servers support a limit in the subquery. This **might** effect performance. The more complecated functions don't work in a subquery. Try to keep those simple.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following to execute this in a single query:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($uid);
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
  p.*
FROM profile as p
  INNER JOIN followrelations as fl
    ON fl.iduser1 = p.userid
WHERE fl.iduser2 = $id
ORDER BY username
SQL;
$stmt = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)){
// Rest of the logic here
}
```

This will return all the fields in your `profile` table. Note that the `mysql_` extension is deprecated and unsafe - you should not be using it in new code. Take a look at [How to replace MySQL functions with PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28096054/3794472) and [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3794472) for some good practices regarding this.

Comment: Found my mistake, the second $sql should be another name and the second half should all be within the first while.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake, the second $sql should be another name (I named it $sql1), and the second half should all be within the first while.

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM followrelations Where iduser2='$uid' "); //followers session uid

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){


    $userid1 = $row['iduser1']; 


      $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile where iduser='$userid1' ORDER BY username ");//get followers infor from profile using variable
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){ 
        $iduserf = $row['iduser'];  //userid2 requires different var name so program does not get mixed up                      
        $username = $row['username'];
        $bio = $row['bio'];
        $avatar = $row['avatar'];

    echo "
    <div style='width:500px;height:100px;padding:20px 20px;float:left;border: solid black 1px;'>
    <a href='profile.php?uid=$iduserf'><img src=$avatar height=50px width=50px /></a></br>
    <a href='profile.php?uid=$iduserf'>$username </a></br>
    </div>" ;                                   
    }
    }
```