# Outdated MYSQL database codes failing to fetch data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I asked a previous question about my data from SQL database is failing to fetch data.
I did the database connection to the server well and it shows "successfully connected" but as my codes are outdated, the server is failing to fetch data from the SQL database.  I was suggested to use PDO but i am a beginner so, I would like help to correct my codes for "search.php":

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
?>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MySQL table search</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style>
BODY, TD {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="search.php">
<label for="from">From</label>
<input name="from" type="text" id="from" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["from"]; ?>" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input name="to" type="text" id="to" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["to"]; ?>"/>
<label>Hotels:</label>
<input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="<?php echo stripcslashes($_REQUEST["string"]); ?>" />
<label>City</label>
<select name="city">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY city ORDER BY city";
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
echo "<option value='".$row["city"]."'".($row["city"]==$_REQUEST["city"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["city"]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<label>Star</label>
<select name="star">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY star ORDER BY star";
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
echo "<option value='".$row["star"]."'".($row["star"]==$_REQUEST["star"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["star"]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
</label>
<button><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="search.php">reset</a></button>
</form>
<br /><br />
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<td width="90" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>From date</strong></td>
<td width="95" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>To date</strong></td>
<td width="159" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Hotel Name</strong></td>
<td width="191" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>City</strong></td>
<td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Star</strong></td>
<td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Links</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
$search_string = " AND (hotel LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR email LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')"; 
}
if ($_REQUEST["city"]<>'') {
$search_city = " AND city='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["city"])."'";   
}
if ($_REQUEST["star"]<>'') {
$search_star = " AND star='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["star"])."'";   
}
if ($_REQUEST["links"]<>'') {
$search_links = " AND links='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["links"])."'";    
}
if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city.$search_string.$search_star.$search_string.$search_links;
} else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_city.$    search_string.$search_star.$search_string.$search_links;
} else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city.$search_string.$search_star.$search_string.$search_links;
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_city.$search_string.$search_star.$search_string.$search_links;
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["from_date"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["to_date"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["hotel"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["city"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["star"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["links"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="7">No results found.</td>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
<script>
$(function() {
var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 2,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
instance.settings.dateFormat ||
$.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
selectedDate, instance.settings );
dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
}
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The "search.php" fetches data from the mysql database and displays the data in a table and also has an option to search data directly on the table.

Comment: use mysqli_query, mysqli_num_rows and mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_  for now and research PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace MySQL functions with PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096054/how-to-replace-mysql-functions-with-pdo)

Comment: Thanks @ArjanShrestha for the help. I can replace it but i might do some mistakes replacing another one by mistake.
can someone replace it for me and paste it in a comment?
i would have done it but i am that good now. I would really appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to learn to use PDO and prepared statements. This is your edited code, I have only changed your mysql_ parts to mysqli_. I hope your $sql and $connection works perfectly

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
?>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MySQL table search</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style>
BODY, TD {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="search.php">
<label for="from">From</label>
<input name="from" type="text" id="from" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["from"]; ?>" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input name="to" type="text" id="to" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["to"]; ?>"/>
<label>Hotels:</label>
<input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="<?php echo stripcslashes($_REQUEST["string"]); ?>" />
<label>City</label>
<select name="city">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY city ORDER BY city";
$sql_result = mysql_query ($connection, $sql) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
echo "<option value='".$row["city"]."'".($row["city"]==$_REQUEST["city"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["city"]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<label>Star</label>
<select name="star">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY star ORDER BY star";
$sql_result = mysqli_query ($connection, $sql) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
echo "<option value='".$row["star"]."'".($row["star"]==$_REQUEST["star"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["star"]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
</label>
<button><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="search.php">reset</a></button>
</form>
<br /><br />
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<td width="90" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>From date</strong></td>
<td width="95" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>To date</strong></td>
<td width="159" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Hotel Name</strong></td>
<td width="191" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>City</strong></td>
<td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Star</strong></td>
<td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Links</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
$search_string = " AND (hotel LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR email LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')"; 
}
if ($_REQUEST["city"]<>'') {
$search_city = " AND city='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["city"])."'";   
}
if ($_REQUEST["star"]<>'') {
$search_star = " AND star='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["star"])."'";   
}
if ($_REQUEST["links"]<>'') {
$search_links = " AND links='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["links"])."'";    
}
if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city.$search_string.$search_star.$search_string.$search_links;
} else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_city.$search_string.$search_star.$search_string.$search_links;
} else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city.$search_string.$search_star.$search_string.$search_links;
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_city.$search_string.$search_star.$search_string.$search_links;
}

$sql_result = mysqli_query ($connection,$sql) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["from_date"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["to_date"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["hotel"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["city"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["star"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["links"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="7">No results found.</td>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
<script>
$(function() {
var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 2,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
instance.settings.dateFormat ||
$.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
selectedDate, instance.settings );
dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
}
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried but it still not works, the table and command buttons is the PHP is not even displaying .  Please help guys and this post can help future people in need.  Thanks
Can someone edit my code and correct the mistakes?