# Mysqli object oriented can store a row of data?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am actually using this to store and know some fields of my database:

```
$conn_2 = dbConnect();
$stmt2 = $conn_2->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, type FROM BrokerMaster.users WHERE email = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $type);
while ($stmt2->fetch()) {
       printf("%s %s %s\n", $firstname, $lastname, $type);
}
```

But I would like to do something like:

```
$stmt2 = $conn_2->prepare("SELECT * FROM BrokerMaster.users WHERE email = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($result); //??
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch()) {
       $firstname = $row["firstname"]
}
```

I couldn't find a way to do it object oriented. The problem I found is that the `$result` is not a `mysqli_result` class (if I am not wrong) and unlike `query()` the `execute()` and `bind_results()` don't create it. (I also couldn't manage to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28096059/2886003)

What are my mistakes (or misunderstandings)?  How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but you would use [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) function.

So you use `fetch_assoc()` on the `mysqli_result`. Doing it in a while loop, will continue cycling until there are available rows.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Use $row["column_field"];
}
```

**Edit**
It happens that we can't get result object straight from a prepared statement.

```
$stmt2->store_result(); 
$result = $stmt2->get_result();
```

Now you should be able to use `fetch_assoc()` over your `mysqli_result`

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue, I don't use `$mysqli->query` to avoid MySQL injection, so I can't obtain a $result with `$mysqli->query($query)`.  and binding it doesn't return a mysqli_result object

Comment: @Llopis I have updated the answer. These are the only information I could find and I can't test it right now

Comment: `get_result` return a [resultset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) which I don't know if it is a mysqli_result, as far as I tested it isn't. Thanks for your effort.