# How to delete a record in database using php? I have some of my codes in deleting but it won't delete the record

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my deleteriddle.php but it doesn't work. Please help me

```
<?php

require("dbcon.php");

$ridid = isset ($_GET['riddleid'])?$_GET['riddleid']:"";
$query = sprintf("DELETE FROM riddle WHERE riddleid= '$ridid'");
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Riddle successfully delete");
    window.location.href = "viewriddle.php";
    </script>';
}

mysql_close($dbcon);

?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `mysql` brrrrrrrrr.... please use something better like `mysqli` or [`PDO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096054/how-to-replace-mysql-functions-with-pdo/28096059#28096059).

Comment: there is no error. It always say that the riddle successfully deleted but when it goes back to view.php the record is still there

Comment: Is this posts related to this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626634/how-to-delete-the-currently-displayed-record-using-php

Comment: I'm sorry Im kinda new to programming so I don't really know what is mysqli or PDO. please bear with me

Comment: yes it is. I'm also the one who posted it

Comment: Please look that up. Those newer libraries are safer when it comes to SQL-injection.

Comment: I would like to look into it but I don't have much time. This website I'm making is due tomorrow. please help me

Comment: but in the query DELETE FROM, whenever I specify the id like.. delete from riddle where riddleid = 1. It has deleted the record with the ID 1. but when I use the '$ridid' it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$query = sprintf("DELETE FROM riddle WHERE riddleid= %u", $ridid);
```

Comment: Try to print the `$query` just before the `mysql_query`. Check its right or not ??

Comment: still nothing happens. but in the query DELETE FROM, whenever I specify the id like.. delete from riddle where riddleid = 1. It has deleted the record with the ID 1. but when I use the '$ridid' it doesn't work

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the `$ridid` in your query and try

Comment: when I removed the single quote..Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1