# Autocomplete TextBox using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am doing autocomplete using PHP but I'm getting an error with the following code so please help me.

**INDEX.PHP**

this is my HTML code

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="txtpname" id="txtpname" size="30" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter City or ZIP code">
</form>
```

this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#txtpname").autocomplete({
            source:'ajax_autocomplete_party.php',
            minLength:1
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is my ajax file from where i get data. `ajax_autocomplete_party.php`
include "script/db.php";

```
$term=$_GET["txtpname"];

 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM party_details where NAME like '%".$term."%' order by NAME");
 $json=array();

while($party=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $json[]=array(
        'value'=> $party["PARTY_ID"],
        'label'=>$party["NAME"]
    );
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

I'm getting an error while my page reload error is: `autocomplete not defined` what to do now

Comment: SQL-injection possible here. Also use of unsafe deprecated mysql library. Use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096054/how-to-replace-mysql-functions-with-pdo/28096059#28096059) or MySQLI

Comment: Do you see anthing in the console (particularly the network tab) about not being able to load the jquery and jqueryui script files?

Comment: `autocomplete not defined` means that it couldn't find the autocomplete library.

Comment: maybe trying newer version of jquery ui will help.

Comment: @Mouser what to do now??? i am not getting anything ryt now

Comment: It works [here](http://jsbin.com/siresulatu/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest version of jQuery and -UI makes it work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtpname").autocomplete({
    source: [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ],
    minLength: 1
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="txtpname" id="txtpname" size="30" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter City or ZIP code">
</form>
```