# Fatal Error: Uncaught Error in PHP with MySQL

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a login page. But i have a problem to login the page.
My login page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="frm">
        <form action="process.php" method="POST">
            <p>
                <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="user" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Login"/>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My process.php file is

```
<?php
    $username=$_POST['user'];
    $password=$_POST['pass'];

    $username = stripcslashes($username);
    $password = stripcslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("login");

    $result = mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and password = '$password' ") or die("Failed to query database".mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if($row['username']==$username && $row['password'] == $password){
        echo"Login success!!! Welcome ".$row['username'];

    }
    else{
        echo"Login Fail ";
    }

?>
```

But i get the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\process.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\process.php on line 7
```

Purpose of this code is to login a page with a particular username and password which are already store in database.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? The `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated since version 5.5 and removed since version 7.

Comment: If you're running PHP<7, the second duplicate will offer some suggestions as to what your problem might be.

Comment: PHP 7.2.10 . This is the version i am used

Comment: You will need to convert to [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) then...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096054/how-to-replace-mysql-functions-with-pdo

Comment: Still I get some warnings:Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\process.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\process.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\process.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\process.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\process.php

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as simple as just changing the word `mysql` to `mysqli`. :-( If you read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli it has information on some other things you will need to change.