# Unable to update multiple records into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Unable to update the multiple records into mysql by using foreach in php with the following error;

```
foreach( $_POST['edit'] AS $edit ) {
    $fromdate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fromdate'][$edit]);
    $todate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['todate'][$edit]);
    $total=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total'][$edit]);
    $ampm=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ampm'][$edit]);
    $Update_leavedetails .= "UPDATE leaverequestdetails SET fromdate='$fromdate', " . "todate='$todate',total='$total',ampm='$ampm' " . "WHERE tranid = '$edit';";
}

if(!mysql_query($Update_leavedetails)){
    die('Invaild query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    .....
```

> Invaild query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'UPDATE leaverequestdetails SET fromdate='2019-08-26',
>   todate='2019-08-26',total=' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run multiple queries at once, which `mysql_query` doesn't support. You need to bring the execution of the query into the loop i.e.

```
foreach( $_POST['edit'] AS $edit ) {
    $fromdate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fromdate'][$edit]);
    $todate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['todate'][$edit]);
    $total=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total'][$edit]);
    $ampm=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ampm'][$edit]);
    $Update_leavedetails = "UPDATE leaverequestdetails SET fromdate='$fromdate', ".
    "todate='$todate',total='$total',ampm='$ampm' ".
    "WHERE tranid = '$edit';";
    if(!mysql_query($Update_leavedetails)){
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

You really need to stop using the `mysql_*` interface, it has been deprecated since PHP5.5 and removed as of PHP7. Upgrade to [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli) can help) or better yet [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096054/how-to-replace-mysql-functions-with-pdo) can help). While you are in the process, change to prepared statements ([MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)), they will protect from injection far better than `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Using MySQLi prepared statements, you would write

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE leaverequestdetails SET fromdate=?, todate=?,total=?,ampm=? WHERE tranid = ?");
foreach( $_POST['edit'] AS $edit ) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $_POST['fromdate'][$edit], $_POST['todate'][$edit], $_POST['total'][$edit], $_POST['ampm'][$edit], $edit);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) die($stmt->error);
}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that your application should not die with the error message. This could be a huge security issue.

Comment: @Dharman that's a fair comment, and I'm assuming (possibly without justification) that OP will deal with that before going into production. But OPs original code had it in there and I was trying to make as few changes as possible.