# php while loop + where

Tags: php, mysql

> list table

- id
- name
- illness
- recipe
- directions

  ```
  $illness = 'Highblood';
  $list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list ",$con);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($list, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   $test[] = $row['recipe'];
   $test2[] = $row['directions'];
   }
  ```

I want to only get the rows

- $row['recipe'];
- $row['directions'];

if the value of illness column is equals to highblood.
how do I do this?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you should *not* be using mysql_* today. Consider PDO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859477/why-are-phps-mysql-functions-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to make some search on google to learn MySQL if you can't do basic query like this.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE illness = '".$illness."'",$con);
```

Comment: did this at first but It has the same effects with
$list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list ",$con);
because i still get the rows of recipe of other illness like Anemia

Comment: @sadbeginner then you did something wrong. Read this : http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php

Answer (score 2):

Select only required rows.

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT recipe,directions FROM list WHERE illness='Highblood'",$con);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($list, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  $test[] = $row['recipe'];
  $test2[] = $row['directions'];
}
```